# How insert the value in specific date for the groups?

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to create a column that every time shows the value which was on `2020-05-15` in `Audi` column and this is needed to be grouped by column `kind`. As a result, the column should show for CUs only 169507, Fnds 49661 ...

I was trying to do it with `dplyr` and using `ungroup()` at the end, however, was not successful in that.

```
df<-structure(list(day = structure(c(18397, 18397, 18397, 18397, 
18397, 18404, 18404, 18404, 18404, 18404, 18411, 18411, 18411, 
18411, 18411), class = "Date"), kind = c("CUs", "Fnds", "IFCI", 
"OPs", "OFs", "CUs", "Fnds", "IFCI", "OPs", "OFs", "IFCI", "CUs", 
"OFs", "OPs", "Fnds"), AUDI = c(169507, 49661, 101383, 633605, 
22108, 170566, 49280, 109490, 626342, 23448, 109831, 172303, 
25029, 643138, 49403), BMW= c(15657, 50841, 727780, 114076, 
74940, 15264, 48505, 743130, 75121, 71945, 752998, 15328, 71649, 
115422, 47686), Lexus= c(185164, 100502, 829163, 747681, 97048, 
185830, 97785, 852620, 701463, 95393, 862829, 187631, 96678, 
758560, 97089)), row.names = 606:620, class = "data.frame")
```

Output should be

[image]

Comment: Would you please a bit more on how your desired output would look like?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Attached to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(kind) %>%
  filter(day == '2020-05-15') %>%
  select(kind, new_col=AUDI) %>%
  right_join(df, by=c("kind")) %>%
  select(day, kind, AUDI, BMW, Lexus, new_col)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 15 x 6
# Groups:   kind [5]
   day        kind    AUDI    BMW  Lexus new_col
   <date>     <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2020-05-15 CUs   169507  15657 185164  169507
 2 2020-05-22 CUs   170566  15264 185830  169507
 3 2020-05-29 CUs   172303  15328 187631  169507
 4 2020-05-15 Fnds   49661  50841 100502   49661
 5 2020-05-22 Fnds   49280  48505  97785   49661
 6 2020-05-29 Fnds   49403  47686  97089   49661
 7 2020-05-15 IFCI  101383 727780 829163  101383
 8 2020-05-22 IFCI  109490 743130 852620  101383
 9 2020-05-29 IFCI  109831 752998 862829  101383
10 2020-05-15 OPs   633605 114076 747681  633605
11 2020-05-22 OPs   626342  75121 701463  633605
12 2020-05-29 OPs   643138 115422 758560  633605
13 2020-05-15 OFs    22108  74940  97048   22108
14 2020-05-22 OFs    23448  71945  95393   22108
15 2020-05-29 OFs    25029  71649  96678   22108
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following solution, I guess based on your question description the value in `day` column your are looking for is `2020-05-15`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  group_by(kind) %>%
  mutate(across(AUDI, ~ .x[day == ymd("2020-05-15")], .names = "new_{.col}")) %>%
  arrange(kind)


# A tibble: 15 x 6
# Groups:   kind [5]
   day        kind    AUDI    BMW  Lexus new_AUDI
   <date>     <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 2020-05-15 CUs   169507  15657 185164   169507
 2 2020-05-22 CUs   170566  15264 185830   169507
 3 2020-05-29 CUs   172303  15328 187631   169507
 4 2020-05-15 Fnds   49661  50841 100502    49661
 5 2020-05-22 Fnds   49280  48505  97785    49661
 6 2020-05-29 Fnds   49403  47686  97089    49661
 7 2020-05-15 IFCI  101383 727780 829163   101383
 8 2020-05-22 IFCI  109490 743130 852620   101383
 9 2020-05-29 IFCI  109831 752998 862829   101383
10 2020-05-15 OFs    22108  74940  97048    22108
11 2020-05-22 OFs    23448  71945  95393    22108
12 2020-05-29 OFs    25029  71649  96678    22108
13 2020-05-15 OPs   633605 114076 747681   633605
14 2020-05-22 OPs   626342  75121 701463   633605
15 2020-05-29 OPs   643138 115422 758560   633605
```